# xslt 1.0 for filtering important elements

Tags: xml, xslt, filter

I am searching for a xsl code which filters some important elements of a given xml data file. The following example shows the whole data about a father and his two children.

This file is my input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <is_parent>true</is_parent>
    <name>Sam</name>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <age>45</age>
    <body_properties>
        <heigth>183</heigth>
        <weight>86</weight>
        <eye_color>green</eye_color>
    </body_properties>

    <person>
        <is_parent>false</is_parent>
        <name>Julia</name>
        <sex>female</sex>
        <age>11</age>
        <body_properties>
            <heigth>155</heigth>
            <weight>40</weight>
            <eye_color>blue</eye_color>
        </body_properties>
    </person>

    <person>
        <is_parent>false</is_parent>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <age>4</age>
        <body_properties>
            <heigth>100</heigth>
            <weight>35</weight>
            <eye_color>brown</eye_color>
        </body_properties>
    </person>
</person>
```

Sometimes I only would like to have the "most important" information.
For example I need the name, the age and the eye color.

This data have to be in my output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name>Sam</name>
    <age>45</age>
    <body_properties>
        <eye_color>green</eye_color>
    </body_properties>

    <person>
        <name>Julia</name>
        <age>11</age>
        <body_properties>
            <eye_color>blue</eye_color>
        </body_properties>
    </person>

    <person>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <age>4</age>
        <body_properties>
            <eye_color>brown</eye_color>
        </body_properties>
    </person>
</person>
```

Sometimes I only would like to have OTHER "most important" information.
For example I need the sex, height and weight. And of course in this case I need another xsl file.

As an additional requirement, the xsl have to support input data files without parents, for example:

```
<person>
     <is_parent>false</is_parent>
     <name>Peter</name>
     <sex>male</sex>
     <age>23</age>
     <body_properties>
         <heigth>195</heigth>
         <weight>99</weight>
         <eye_color>blue</eye_color>
     </body_properties>
 </person>
```

These examples are simplified in order to explain my requirements. The really xml files are much bigger with a lot of elements.

But all xml input files have the structure without childs:

```
<person>
   ...
</person>
```

or the structure with childs

```
<person>
    ...

    <person>
       ...
    </person>

    <person>
       ...
    </person>

    <person>
       ...
    </person>
</person>
```

Do you have any ideas for a xslt solution in xsl version 1.0 ?
Please do not hand out the advice to change the input file format. It is not possible for me.

Comment: What have you tried with XSL? Can you show us the XSL you are using and why it's not working the way you want?

Comment: "I am searching for a xsl code which filters some important elements of a given xml data file" - perhaps you should learn a little about XSLT instead of trying to copy code which you don't understand. You will get more help if you TRY to code a solution and post the area of code which is relevant instead of asking for someone to code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a collegue for help and got support. 
The following code works for me.
May be the templates with match /person/person and /person could be implemented without "Don't Repeat Yourself" ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" media-type="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/person/person">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="age"/>

            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/person">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="age"/>

            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body_properties">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="eye_color"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- catch all unhandled elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```